# ranged pair of cells match pair of cells on another sheet display result on first sheet

Tags: excel-formula

On sheet "96-97" If pair of cells L and M ranged from ROW 9497 to 13240 match (both need to match) pair of cells G and H on sheet "CNP" from Row 12133 to 24125 => then on sheet "96-97" display what's inside from corresponding ROW on O, P , Q, R and S COLUMN (from "CNP" sheet ) to corresponding row on sheet 96-97 on Columns N, O, P, Q, R.

Shortly: if 9497 L `on sheet 1` match 12133 G on `sheet 2` AND 9497 M `on sheet 1` match 12133 H on `sheet 2` **then on the same row** in `sheet 1` but on columns N,O,P,Q,R DISPLAY what's inside matching row from  columns O,P,Q,R,S.

I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking, but could you post example data with example results?

Answer (score 0):

In row 2, column O put:

```
=IF(Sheet1!L9497=Sheet2!G12133 & Sheet1!M9497=Sheet2!H12133, Sheet2!O2,"")
```

assuming you want blanks if the condition isn't met. I'm also assuming you want to copy what's in Sheet2 to Sheet1 in the O,P,Q,R and S columns, although you don't say so. Then you can copy this formula to your other rows and columns.